# how to loop a range for a value before adding a value to next available row

Tags: vba, loops, range

I'm setting up a button to check a range for a value if the value don't exist then copy value to next available row

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim LrowCompleted As String
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox "DON'T DO THAT"
    Else
        LrowCompleted = Sheets("Budget").range("N4").End(xlDown).Row
        Sheets("Budget").range("N" & LrowCompleted + 1) = TextBox1.Text
        Unload Me
        MechanicalEquipment.Show
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Does your code above work? Is it giving an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First. LrowCompleted should be a Long not a String.

Second. You need to build the Find portion. Are you only going to find this value in a single column? Example below. Not tested but it should work.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim LrowCompleted As Long, fText as String, Dim findValue As Range
    fText = TextBox1.Text
    'You probably dont need to check all 3 below but I'm not on excel to check the best one to use.
    If fText = "" Or fText = Nothing Or fText = Null Then
        MsgBox "Provide what to look for"
    Else
        Set findValue = Sheets("Budget").Columns("N:N").Find(fText, Range("N1"), xlValues, xlPart, xlByColumns, xlNext)
        If findValue Is Nothing Then
            'Nothing found lets place it at the end
            LrowCompleted = Sheets("Budget").Range("N4").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Sheets("Budget").Range("N" & LrowCompleted) = fText
            Unload Me
            MechanicalEquipment.Show
        Else
            'I found something, do nothing i guess
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```